# Cannot access Team Foundation Server using port 8080

Tags: tfs

I have just installed a Team Foundation Server 2015 update 3 on a Windows Server 2016, the web interface of the TFS is accessible on the server itself (http://192.168.0.10:8080/tfs), but if I try the same address on my client it does not work, but it does respond on http://192.168.0.10. I have checked that port 8080 is allowed in the firewall of the server. What could be the issue?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "does not work"?

Comment: What the error message you get when access to it from your client PC? Can you share a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

It was simply the firewall that was blocking the site, since I added a rule for this "8080" it worked as excpected. And even if its not in the list over supported OS it do work with Windows Server 2016.

Answer (score 0):

TFS 2015 only supports the following server operating systems:

- Windows Server 2012 R2 (Essentials, Standard, Datacenter)
- Windows Server 2012 (Essentials, Standard, Datacenter)
- Windows Server 2008 R2 (minimum SP1) (Standard, Enterprise, Datacenter)

Windows Server 2016 is not supported currently.

[image]